# Sort List of JSONObjects on different scenarios

Tags: java, json, sorting

I have a List of JSONObjects like,

```
[{"id":"aaa", "value":"-1"}, {"id":"bbb", "value":"10"}, {"id":"ccc", "value":"20"}, {"id":"ddd", "value":"-"}, {"id":"eee", "value":"-10"}]
```

I have to sort this List based on the values of each JSONObject both in ascending and descending directions. But the values having "-" should always be shown at last in both ascending and descending cases.
In one more case, we should only show positive values, considering the negative values as "-". 
How can I handle both these cases together in the best way possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve it using Jackson:

```
String str = "[{\"id\":\"aaa\", \"value\":\"-1\"}, {\"id\":\"bbb\", \"value\":\"10\"}, {\"id\":\"ccc\", \"value\":\"20\"}, {\"id\":\"ddd\", \"value\":\"-\"}, {\"id\":\"eee\", \"value\":\"-10\"}]";
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
List<SomeClass> list = om.readValue(str, new TypeReference<List<SomeClass>>() {});
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> {
    try {return Integer.parseInt(o.getValue());}
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {return Integer.MAX_VALUE;}
}));
System.out.println(list);
```

For changing the direction of comparator, invoke `.reversed()` on the `Comparator`. Eg `Comparator.comparingInt(...).reversed()`.

Comment: When we call .reversed(), the dashed values ("-") will come at first right?

Comment: @SAKTHIVELN Yes, but I can see that you don't want it. You can just create a comparator according to your needs in this scenario.